# How to deal with NSLayoutConstraint verbosity in code?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have come to appreciate the work that [Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) does for me, but I'm with Brent Simmons on the topic of [not using Interface Builder](http://inessential.com/2013/03/06/how_much_or_how_little_i_use_interface) to set up the constraints. The interface as provided by Apple is flexible but *extremely verbose* — clearly designed for code generator instead of human use. For me it exemplifies the worst of Objective-C with repeating overlong identical prefixes and rarely used parameters obfuscating all meaning instead of providing clarity to the code. I've seen [Florian Kugler's FLKAutoLayout](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/making-autolayout-code-less-painful) that hides the constraint creation in category on `UIView`.

Are there other ways to make the layout constraints in code cleaner and easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to stay as close as possible to the Apple's implementation, acknowledging the existence of `NSLayoutConstraint`, so I have simply defined a set of **[Concise Auto Layout macros](https://gist.github.com/palimondo/5998280)** that remove the prefixes from attributes and relations and wrap the constraint creation in a constructor function-like macros (also omitting the multiplier parameter that I never use):

- `Constraint`
- `ConstantConstraint`
- `VisualConstraints`
- `VisualConstraintWithMetrics`

To attach multiple simple constraints to view, I wrap them in array literal. I always prefix non-zero constants with a sign, to emphasize the displacement. In practice it looks like this (instance variables reffer to views):

```c
[self.view addConstraints:
 @[Constraint(_verticalSeparator, CenterX, Equal, _top, CenterX, 0),
 Constraint(_verticalSeparator, CenterY, Equal, _top, CenterY, +22),
 Constraint(_verticalSeparator, Height, Equal, _localWeather, Height, 0),
 Constraint(_localWeather, CenterY, Equal, _verticalSeparator, CenterY, 0),
 Constraint(_addLocation, CenterY, Equal, _verticalSeparator, CenterY, 0),
 Constraint(_touchDown, Trailing, Equal, _verticalSeparator, Trailing, -1),
 Constraint(_touchDown, CenterY, Equal, _localWeather, CenterY, 0),
 Constraint(_touchDown, Width, Equal, _localWeather, Width, +26),
 Constraint(_touchDown, Height, Equal, _localWeather, Height, 0)
]];

id f = @"[_localWeather]-space-[_verticalSeparator]-space-[_addLocation]";
[self.view addConstraints:
 VisualConstraintWithMetrics(f, @{@"space": @11},
                             _localWeather, _verticalSeparator, _addLocation)];


[_tableCell addConstraint:ConstantConstraint(_tableCell, Height, Equal, 44)];
```

When dealing with group of views that all share the same setup, I enumerate over array literal like this:

```c
[@[_top, _middle, _bottom, _touchDown, _verticalSeparator]
 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}];
```

Filling the `superview` horizontally happened often enough, that its lifted into its own macro:

```c
[@[_top, _middle, _bottom] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:horizontallyFillSuperview];
```

I'll update this answer as my style evolves…

Answer (score 9):

[Masonry](https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry) by Jonas Budelmann is a DSL for Auto Layout which is much more readable than lines and lines of layout constraints being created manually. 
Via [iOS Dev Weekly](http://iosdevweekly.com/issues/104/).

```
UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top);
    make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
    make.right.equalTo(superview.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
}];
```

It also has composite constraints for setting edges, size and center:

```c
// make top, left, bottom, right equal view2
make.edges.equalTo(view2);

// make top = superview.top + 5, left = superview.left + 10,
//      bottom = superview.bottom - 15, right = superview.right - 20
make.edges.equalTo(superview).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 10, 15, 20))

// make width and height greater than or equal to titleLabel
make.size.greaterThanOrEqualTo(titleLabel) 

// make width = superview.width + 100, height = superview.height - 50
make.size.equalTo(superview).sizeOffset(CGSizeMake(100, -50))

// make centerX and centerY = button1
make.center.equalTo(button1) 

// make centerX = superview.centerX - 5, centerY = superview.centerY + 10
make.center.equalTo(superview).centerOffset(CGPointMake(-5, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Parus](https://github.com/DAlOG/Parus) lib for specify your constraints.
Main idea of this lib is to not distanciate from NSLayoutConstraint itself, and allow you to operate with constraint as you want.

For example:

```
[self.view addConstraints:
@[Constraint(_verticalSeparator, CenterX, Equal, _top, CenterX, 0),
  Constraint(_verticalSeparator, CenterY, Equal, _top, CenterY, +22),
  Constraint(_verticalSeparator, Height, Equal, _localWeather, Height, 0),
  Constraint(_localWeather, CenterY, Equal, _verticalSeparator, CenterY, 0),
  Constraint(_addLocation, CenterY, Equal, _verticalSeparator, CenterY, 0),
  Constraint(_touchDown, Trailing, Equal, _verticalSeparator, Trailing, -1),
  Constraint(_touchDown, CenterY, Equal, _localWeather, CenterY, 0),
  Constraint(_touchDown, Width, Equal, _localWeather, Width, +26),
  Constraint(_touchDown, Height, Equal, _localWeather, Height, 0)
]];

id f = @"[_localWeather]-space-[_verticalSeparator]-space-[_addLocation]";
[self.view addConstraints:
VisualConstraintWithMetrics(f, @{@"space": @11},
                         _localWeather, _verticalSeparator, _addLocation)];
```

will look like:

```
[self.view addConstraints PVGroup(@[
  PVCenterXOf(_verticalSeparator).equalTo.centerXOf(_top),
  PVCenterYOf(_verticalSeparator).equalTo.centerYOf(_top).plus(22),
  PVHeightOf(_verticalSeparator).equalTo.heightOf(_localWeather),
  PVCenterYOf(_localWeather).equalTo.centerYOf(_verticalSeparator),
  PVCenterYOf(_addLocation).equalTo.centerYOf(_verticalSeparator),
  PVTrailingOf(_touchDown).equalTo.trailingOf(_verticalSeparator).minus(1),
  PVCenterYOf(_touchDown).equalTo.centerYOf(_localWeather),
  PVWidthOf(_touchDown).equalTo.widthOf(_localWeather).plus(26),
  PVHightOf(_touchDown).equalTo.heightOf(_localWeather),
  PVVFL("[_localWeather]-space-[_verticalSeparator]-space-[_addLocation]"),
]).withViews(NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_localWeather, _verticalSeparator, _addLocation))
  .withMetrics(@{@"space": @11}).asArray];
```

Also [Parus](https://github.com/DAlOG/Parus) can handle incorrect cases like

```
Constraint(_verticalSeparator, CenterY, Equal, _top, Width, +22)
```

and others.